# SSH Connection to EC2 Timeout After **Mac** Reboot

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, mac-osx, mac

Apple introduced an update 10.15.5 that causes my computer to crash every 30 minutes. Thanks Apple. I am working with Amazon's EC2. Twice now, I have ssh'ed into an instance, been doing work, and then my computer crashes and reboots. Once it does this, I am then unable to re-connect to my instance. It times out every time. The only solution I have found is to terminate the instance and start a new instance.

(Yes the host name and the command are correct because I save the command to a text file and re-use that command every time. When I start a new instance, I replace the public IP.)

In summary, I can connect easily before the **Mac** reboot (not EC2 reboot, as I have seen similar questions here in my search), and am unable to connect after.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the public IP was wrong as I was using the one from the first server I terminated.

I can ssh into the second one.

Still unsure what happened with the original server that I had to terminate, but the second one seems to work currently.